# Ruby implementation is_numeric? for Strings, need better alternatives

Tags: ruby, string, numerical

I wanted to validate 'numericality' of a string (its not an attribute in an active-record model). I just need it to be a valid base 10, positive integer string. I am doing this:

```
class String
  def numeric?
    # Check if every character is a digit
    !!self.match(/\A[0-9]+\Z/)
  end
end

class String
  def numeric?
    # Check is there is *any* non-numeric character
    !self.match(/[^0-9]/)
  end
end
```

Which of these is a more plausible alternative? OR, is there any other better implementation?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why the `{1,1}` multiplier? By default all character classes and literals are matched exactly once unless otherwise specified. This is redundant.

Comment: Poor me! I'll remove it at once.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694176/retrieve-number-from-the-string-pattern-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please make sure use `\A` and `\Z` rather than `^` and `$`, to match the entire string rather than just a single line in the string.  If you want to avoid matching a string with an ending newline, use '\z' at the end.  For more issues, see [The Regex Tutorial on anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

For example, `/^[0-9]+$/` successfully matches the following:

```
foo
1234
bar
```

but `/\A[0-9]+\Z/` does not.

Answer (score 5):

The first one looks sane to me.

I'd name the method `numeric?`, though. I'm not a big fan of `is_foo?` methods. They make sense in languages that doesn't have question marks in method names (`is_foo`, `isFoo`), but with the question mark, the `is` feels redundant.

Comment: I ended up using the second one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a 100% certain but Rails seems to be using `/\A[+-]?\d+\Z/` for integers.
Click on show source for `validates_numericality_of` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M002172)

Comment: \A -> Start of string
\Z -> End of string

Basically the same I am unsing in First one, except the positive/negative modifier part.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest another way of doing it. Also, because you asked "positive" integer, I made two separate methods for positive integer and non-negative integer.

```
class String
  def numeric?
    !self.match(/[^0-9]/)
  end

  def positive_integer?
    self.to_i > 0
  end

  def nonnegative_integer?
    self.to_i > 0 or self == '0'
  end
end
```

Here's the benchmark code:

```
require 'benchmark'
include Benchmark

bmbm(100) do |x|
  x.report('numeric?') do
    "some invalid string".numeric?
  end

  x.report('positive_integer?') do
    "some invalid string".positive_integer?
  end

  x.report('nonnegative_integer?') do
    "some invalid string".nonnegative_integer?
  end
end
```

Result:

```
numeric?
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000045)
positive_integer?
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000012)
nonnegative_integer?
0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000015)
```

It seems like `positive_integer?` and `nonnegative_integer?` are faster in this micro-benchmark.

Finally, as a side note, you can define `integer?` method in a similar fashion:

```
class String
  def integer?
    self.to_i.to_s == self
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The second will finish quicker in the case of a non-numeric string, as it will reject on the first bad character.

Also, check out the String#to_i method - it possibly does what you want:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000787

Comment: the problem with to_i is you never know if it is 0 or not a number.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is fast, but I like:

```
class String
 def numeric?
    true if Integer(object) rescue false
 end
end
```

Handles negative numbers as well. And if you ever wanted to support floats in the future, just use Float()

Comment: Does this really work? Where does `object` come from? On my ruby 1.9.2-p180 it always returns `false` because `object` is undefined.

Comment: I think `object` should be `self` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

According to a simple benchmark, the second approach is faster, although I'm not expert benchmarker, so this might not be a valid benchmark:
http://pastie.org/586777

Zalus' logic is right. It only needs to check once for a non-valid string.

Answer (score 0):

Notice

```
n = '1234'
n.to_i.to_s == n
=> true

n2 = '1.3'
n.to_i.to_s == n2
=> false
```

works for positive & negative integers, but not octal/hex representations, floats etc.  May not perform the best (untested), but no point wasting time with premature optimizations.