# Does ruby 1.9.2 have an is_a? function?

Tags: ruby, weak-typing

I googled that there is an `is_a?` function to check whether an object is an integer or not.

But I tried in rails console, and it doesn't work.

I ran the code like the following:

```
 "1".is_a?
 1.is_a?
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Google is nice, but it's not the first place to look for what is in Ruby's standard and core libraries. I'd recommend going to the primary source: your own machine's `ri`, or the [rubydoc site](http://www.ruby-doc.org/). Entering `ri is_a?` at your command-line could return a couple hits, with the important one being `Object.is_a?`

Comment: Related question for what you're trying to do: [Retrieve number from the string pattern using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694176/retrieve-number-from-the-string-pattern-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a built in function to say if a string is effectively an integer, but you can easily make your own:

```
class String
  def int
    Integer(self) rescue nil
  end
end
```

This works because the Kernel method `Integer()` throws an error if the string can't be converted to an integer, and the inline `rescue nil` turns that error into a nil.

```
Integer("1") -> 1
Integer("1x") -> nil
Integer("x") -> nil
```

and thus:

```
"1".int -> 1 (which in boolean terms is `true`)
"1x".int -> nil
"x".int -> nil
```

You could alter the function to return `true` in the true cases, instead of the integer itself, but if you're testing the string to see if it's an integer, chances are you want to use that integer for something! I very commonly do stuff like this:

```
if i = str.int
  # do stuff with the integer i
else
  # error handling for non-integer strings
end
```

Although if the assignment in a test position offends you, you can always do it like this:

```
i = str.int
if i
  # do stuff with the integer i
else
  # error handling for non-integer strings
end
```

Either way, this method only does the conversion once, which if you have to do a lot of these, may be a significant speed advantage.

[Changed function name from `int?` to `int` to avoid implying it should return just true/false.]

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't see your edit until after I posted this, and it wasn't me who downvoted you.

Comment: -1 because this has nothing to do with the question and because this is a horrible idea. ? methods should return a boolean. 1 is not equal to true.

Comment: Pertains exactly to the question, as the poster clarified in response to Andrew Grimm. Read the whole page before writing, next time. mlzboy, feel free to call your method `int` instead of `int?` if you prefer methods with ? to only return strict booleans. Or any other name you like. (It's his method, I'm just showing him how to do it.)

Comment: I changed it to `int`. The `?` really wasn't the important part.

Answer (score 19):

You forgot to include the class you were testing against:

```
"1".is_a?(Integer) # false
1.is_a?(Integer) # true
```

Comment: thanks, in fact my situation is  i want to check a string is a number,if "1".is_a?(Ingeger) return false,it seems didn't useful for this situation

Comment: @mlzboy: As far as I know, Ruby treats `"1"` as a string, rather than as a potential integer. You have to do `2 + "2".to_i` or `2 + Integer(2)` - you can't do `2 + "2"`. You may want to read [Is ruby strongly or weakly typed ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520228/is-ruby-strongly-or-weakly-typed)

Answer (score 1):

i used a regular expression

```
if a =~ /\d+/
   puts "y"
else
   p 'w'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a function called respond_to? that can be used to seeing if a particular class or object has a method with a certain name. The syntax is something like

```
User.respond_to?('name') # returns true is method name exists
otherwise false
```

http://www.prateekdayal.net/2007/10/16/rubys-responds_to-for-checking-if-a-method-exists/

Comment: `respond_to?` is very different than `is_a?`.

Comment: @Greg: `is_a?` looks at class, whereas `respond_to?` would be useful for duck typing.

Comment: +1: In Ruby, it's preferable to check that the object does what you want it to do, rather than it is an instance of some class.  Ruby relies more upon  "duck typing" than upon strict inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
str = "1"
=> "1"
num = str.to_i
=> 1
num.is_a?(Integer)
=> true

str1 = 'Hello'
=> "Hello"
num1 = str1.to_i
=> 0
num1.is_a?(Integer)
=> true
```

Comment: Both `"1"` and `'hello'` ended up with `true`. Did you mean to do that?

Comment: @Andrew I know that both ended up with true. But I thought there is a difference in that if a string is converted to integer as in "Hello" we get 0 as the value. So this might be the distinguishing point.

Comment: From the String#to_i docs: If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar, but none of these did it for me, but this one does - use "class":

```
a = 11
a.class
=> Fixnum
```