# In ruby, is truthiness idiomatic for a method name ending with a question mark?

Tags: ruby, idioms, truthiness

Is it normal for methods with a question mark to return something that's truthy (for example, a number) to indicate that something is true, or should `true` itself be returned?

Are there any examples of truthiness being used in the Ruby standard library or by Rails, for example?

**Background:** Someone wrote a `String#int?` method in [an answer to a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282273/does-ruby-1-9-2-have-an-is-a-function/4282449#4282449), which returned an integer to represent true, and `nil` to represent false. Another user was surprised at not returning a boolean.

Comment: The example you cite was not following convention, it should have returned an actual boolean.

Comment: Heh, I saw that discussion, and wondered if that response would lead to this question. :-) Good catch @Andrew Grimm

Comment: @Adam: Isn't that an answer, not a comment? (Usually I complain about people doing the opposite!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *usual* for methods ending with `?` to return either `true` or `false` but it is not systematic and no core method will assume it.

An example in the core classes is `Numeric#nonzero?` which *never* returns `true` or `false`.

```
42.nonzero? # => 42
```

The library `Set` has `add?` and `delete?` too. I wish `Enumerable#one?` returned `nil` or `false` to distinguish cases where the count is zero from when it is greater than one.

A similar example are the comparison operators (`<`, `>`, ...), which usually return only `true` or `false`. Here again exceptions exist for `Module`'s operators that will return `nil` instead when the two modules are not related:

```
Array > Enumerable  # => false
Array > Fixnum      # => nil
```

Comment: Heckle also uses [Ternary logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic) internally - IIRC `true` means a method is heckle-proof, `false` means it isn't, and `nil` means it doesn't have anything to heckle.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a ? to a method name in Ruby is idiomatic that the method will return true or false. [Object#nil?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000342) is a good example. In fact, Object has a lot of good examples of truthiness checks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to your question, and both are valid:

Technically, anything returning a `false` or `nil` value acts as a false boolean when doing a conditional test, just as a non-nil or `true` value acts as a true. So, the method in question will work correctly for most times you'd want to know if something is an integer.

But stylistically a method that ends with '?' should return either a Boolean `true` or `false` and only those.

The method in question doesn't really play nicely with our expectations and fails the POLS ("principle of least surprise") because you can reasonably expect a Boolean value being returned, and get an integer or a nil. THAT could lead to unpleasant surprises in  code when it fails with an unexpected `nil` or a Fixnum value.

So, while it's a valid method, it's not a *good* method, and I would have brought it up in a code review. And that leads to a separate discussion of how subtle things like that can enhance or hurt code maintenance, but that's an entirely different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I renamed the method in question to remove the `?`, which was really not important to the question being answered. Scanning through the core functions that end in ?s, the only ones I spotted that returned data or nil were the `add?` and `delete?` methods on Set.

Comment: I removed my comment from your answer: I was wrong.  Thanks for the lesson!