# Should every Ruby method returning a boolean have a question mark?

Tags: ruby

I have a method:

```
def addNewShow(name)

end
```

I want it to return a boolean which states whether or not this was successful. Should my method have a question mark on the end of its name to let the user know that that's what it returns, despite it not being a question, and only returning the answer to the question "Was this successful?"

Comment: No, not unless the method name is suitable as a question. Your method is a verb "add". If it was "added_show?" and tested to see if a particular "show" was added, then yes, it'd make sense. Also, in Ruby, method names are not CamelCase, they're snake_case.

Comment: This has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289629/in-ruby-is-truthiness-idiomatic-for-a-method-name-ending-with-a-question-mark?rq=1

Comment: @ShyamHabarakada No, that’s the inverse of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary for that.  You could include a method to check if a show already exists though:

```
def exists?(show_name)
  #your code to check if it exists
  #return boolean value of true/false for if show is already added or not
end
```

Comment: It is not Ruby's practice to use third-person singular present method names besides a few exceptions (`is_a?`, etc).

Comment: n/m, I read it as "Is it not" rather than "It is not", herp derp.  What is Ruby's practice then, and is it documented somewhere?

Comment: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/5599, http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/5579