# Checking if a variable is an integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does Rails 3 or Ruby have a built-in way to check if a variable is an integer?

For example,

```
1.is_an_int #=> true
"dadadad@asdasd.net".is_an_int #=> false?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does ruby 1.9.2 have an is_a? function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282273/does-ruby-1-9-2-have-an-is-a-function)

Comment: Rather than caring whether a variable is an integer, you should check to see if the variable responds to `to_i`. That's part of Ruby's "duck typing": If it can act like an integer, treat it like one.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Not entirely. "hello".to_i returns 0 which may not be what you expect.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: it is in content, but the question is different.  If you didn't know about "is_a?", you wouldn't know to ask if there is a "is_a?".

Comment: @EinLama, well, to confuse things further, `'0xdeadbeef'.to_i #=> 0` but `'0xdeadbeef'.to_i(16) #=> 3735928559` as does `'deadbeef'.to_i(16) #=> 3735928559` or `'deadbeef'.to_i(16).to_s(16) #=> "deadbeef"`. We're expected to test to make sure we're catching the corner cases but somethings things get slippery. Otherwise we can go old-school and do it asking about types and be more limiting. This is the crux of the arguments surrounding duck-typing.

Comment: @AnApprentice For your information, `kind_of?` is an alias to `is_a?`.

Comment: @JacobRelkin `is_a?` is slightly different; it asks if the object of an instance of a specific class; `kind_of?` asks if it is an instance or child of a specific class.  `fido.is_a? Dog` is true; `fido.kind_of? Animal` is true, for example.

Answer (score 313, accepted):

You can use the `is_a?` method

```
>> 1.is_a? Integer
=> true
>> "dadadad@asdasd.net".is_a? Integer
=> false
>> nil.is_a? Integer
=> false
```

Comment: Thats very cool. does that work to validate email addresses to?

Comment: @AnApprentice Since when was validating email addresses part of the question?

Comment: this wont work if the number comes in a string like "11111111"

Comment: look below `Integer(obj) rescue false`

This will not work for "1" if you want to check if it will convert

Comment: @Ricbermo "1111111" is a String. A String that happens to be convertible to and Integer.

Comment: @AnApprentice you need to use regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: It should return false for decimals, integers are by definition whole numbers.

Comment: @zee Of course it will, as 2.3 is not an Integer, it is a Float. See https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/07/numbers-in-ruby/ for understanding numeric types in Ruby and how they are related.

Answer (score 54):

If you want to know whether an object is an `Integer` *or something which can meaningfully be converted to an Integer* (NOT including things like `"hello"`, which `to_i` will convert to `0`):

```
result = Integer(obj) rescue false
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just a noob, but this tweak would have helped me.   result = Integer(obj) rescue false.

Comment: @JohnCurry, feel free to edit the answer if you can improve it. That's how SO works.

Comment: I did, it got rejected. "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post" But regardless, thank you for your answer, it helped me solve my issue!

Comment: Integer('08') will fail because of the string being interpreted as octal, Integer('08', 10) works fine. Just in case.

Comment: Not sure if `Integer(2.5) => 2` is always a meaningful conversion.

Answer (score 32):

Use a regular expression on a string:

```
def is_numeric?(obj) 
   obj.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true
end
```

If you want to check if a variable is of certain type, you can simply use `kind_of?`:

```
1.kind_of? Integer #true
(1.5).kind_of? Float #true
is_numeric? "545"  #true
is_numeric? "2aa"  #false
```

Comment: This it is exactly what i was looking for the is_numeric?

Comment: I think this is close, but not exactly correct. For instance, it will fail for ".34". The problem, I think, is that in `\d+?` the `?` specifies a non-greedy match, whereas you probably want an optional match. Changing `\d+?` to `\d*` might fix it, but I'd want to run it through a suite of tests to be sure. This also won't match hex or exponential notation, but I'm sure that's fine for certain use cases.

Comment: Why not just to use this regexp: `\A\d+\z`?

Comment: Compare to the `Integer(obj) rescue false` code from @alex-d below; regexp is difficult to read and not clear in its intent.  Both work, I came to this question in an attempt to fix a poorly constructed regexp that was not always working :-)

Answer (score 23):

If you're uncertain of the type of the variable (it could be a string of number characters), say it was a credit card number passed into the params, so it would originally be a string but you want to make sure it doesn't have any letter characters in it, I would use this method:

```
    def is_number?(obj)
        obj.to_s == obj.to_i.to_s
    end

    is_number? "123fh" # false
    is_number? "12345" # true
```

@Benny points out an oversight of this method, keep this in mind:

```
is_number? "01" # false. oops!
```

Comment: thanks, you save my day. For anyone that need to check if it float or not can change directly to `obj.to_s == obj.to_f.to_s` just like in my case.

Comment: Edmund that's clever! 

Comment: Awesome, i prefer this than Integer('123fh') and rescue exception.

Answer (score 5):

There's `var.is_a? Class` (in your case: `var.is_a? Integer`); that might fit the bill.  Or there's `Integer(var)`, where it'll throw an exception if it can't parse it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use triple equal.

```
if Integer === 21 
    puts "21 is Integer"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A more "duck typing" way is to use `respond_to?` this way "integer-like" or "string-like" classes can also be used

```
if(s.respond_to?(:match) && s.match(".com")){
  puts "It's a .com"
else
  puts "It's not"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't need to convert zero values, I find the methods `to_i` and `to_f` to be extremely useful since they will convert the string to either a zero value (if not convertible or zero) or the actual `Integer` or `Float` value.

```
"0014.56".to_i # => 14
"0014.56".to_f # => 14.56
"0.0".to_f # => 0.0
"not_an_int".to_f # 0
"not_a_float".to_f # 0.0

"0014.56".to_f ? "I'm a float" : "I'm not a float or the 0.0 float" 
# => I'm a float
"not a float" ? "I'm a float" : "I'm not a float or the 0.0 float" 
# => "I'm not a float or the 0.0 float"
```

EDIT2 : be careful, the `0` integer value is not falsey it's truthy (`!!0 #=> true`) (thanks @prettycoder)

EDIT

Ah just found out about the dark cases... seems to only happen if the number is in first position though

```
"12blah".to_i => 12
```

Comment: 0 is truthy in ruby!

Comment: @prettycoder thanks for the heads up, I will fix this immediately in the answer

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize on [the answer of Alex D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589968/checking-if-a-variable-is-an-integer#answer-18114479), using [refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Integerable
    refine String do
      def integer?
        Integer(self)
      rescue ArgumentError
        false
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Later, in you class:

```
require 'core_ext/string/integerable'

class MyClass
  using CoreExtensions::Integerable

  def method
    'my_string'.integer?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before trying to determine if something is a string or any sort of number whatsoever. I have tried using a regular expression, but that is not reliable for my use case. Instead, you can check the variable's class to see if it is a descendant of the Numeric class.

```
if column.class < Numeric
  number_to_currency(column)
else
  column.html_safe
end
```

In this situation, you could also substitute for any of the Numeric descendants: BigDecimal, Date::Infinity, Integer, Fixnum, Float, Bignum, Rational, Complex

Answer (score 0):

Basically, an integer **n** is a power of three, if there exists an integer **x** such that **n == 3x**.

So to verify that you can use this functions

```
def is_power_of_three(n)
  return false unless n.positive?

  n == 3**(Math.log10(n)/Math.log10(3)).to_f.round(2)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

**Probably you are looking for something like this:**

Accept "2.0 or 2.0 as an INT but reject 2.1 and "2.1"

> num = 2.0
>
> if num.is_a? String   num = Float(num) rescue false end
>
> new_num = Integer(num) rescue false
>
> puts num
>
> puts new_num
>
> puts num == new_num