# Why is this an integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer

I have the following code in my irb:

```
irb(main):005:0> num = gets.chomp.to_i
,
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> num.is_a? Integer
=> true
irb(main):007:0> num = gets.chomp.to_i
q
=> 0
irb(main):008:0> num.is_a? Integer
=> true
```

I'm really new to ruby and i wonder, why "q" an "," is here an Integer... Could you please explain me why?

Comment: [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) you can read what String#to_i method actually does. Hope it helps.

Comment: @maicher Please have a look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589968/ruby-rails-how-to-check-if-a-var-is-an-integer#4589985

Comment: Yes! Thank you! :) Do you know how i could use an other method which makes sure that the if statement only executes if it's an integer?

Comment: `Integer(",")` will raise an ArgumentError.

Comment: gets method returns string or nil, so there is no way to have an instance of Integer as a result. If you want to be sure that your input is a type of Integer, you could do @zetetic's trick (check = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue false). If an input is an Integer the right side will return the integer (which is other than nil & false, so the if condition will pass), if not it will raise an error and return false (if condition will not pass).

Answer (score 4):

This is the [documentation of `String.to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i).

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0 is returned. This method never raises an exception when base is valid.

As documented, any string where the leading character is not a valid digit, is still converted into an Integer, specifically into 0.

```
",".to_i == 0
# => true
```

Clearly, `0` is an Integer.

Comment: Thank you. I found that out in the docs. is there another possible way to check if an input is an Integer?

Comment: Simply use a regular expression: `/\A\d+\z/.match(num)` where `num` is your input. Keep in mind that you can check if the input is formally valid, but then if you want to use the input as integer you have to convert it since input from keyboard is always a String.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out [`String.to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_i) will convert the string to it's integer counterpart. If a suitable conversion can't be done (i.e. it consists of only a `,`) then `0` will be returned.

If you wanted to conditionally do something if the input was an integer you could do something like:

```
if number = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil
  puts "We have an integer!"
else
  puts "No Integer here...move along"
end
```