# rubocop app controller function validate param integer use of nil? predicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, rubocop, ruby-style-guide

I tried rewriting this function numerous ways to get around this error, however, I want to defer to other experts before I disable the cop around it.

```
  def numeric?(obj)
    obj.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true
  end
```

This is used like so:

```
  def index
    if params[:job_id] && numeric?(params[:job_id])
```

This issue was solved via: [Checking if a variable is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589968/ruby-rails-how-to-check-if-a-var-is-an-integer)

[image]

Update trying:

```
  def numeric?(string)
    !!Kernel.Float(string)
  rescue TypeError, ArgumentError
    false
  end
```

Reference [How do I determine if a string is numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061584/how-do-i-determine-if-a-string-is-numeric)

New error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def numeric?(arg)
  !/\A[+-]?\d+\z/.match(arg.to_s).nil?
end
```

Passes all Rubocop tests from a default configuration. Complete gist with tests at https://gist.github.com/aarontc/d549ee4a82d21d263c9b

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet does the trick:

```
def numeric?(arg)
  return false if arg.is_a?(Float)
  return !Integer(arg).nil? rescue false
end
```

Returns false for the following: `'a'`, `12.34`, and `'12.34'`.

Returns true for the following: `'1'`, `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the method

```
def numeric?(obj)
  obj.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/).nil?
end
```

You really don't need to do `nil` comparisons and then based on the decision returning  `true`/`false`. `#nil?` method does it for you.

Comment: when integer params are passed i.e. "8" it returned false

Comment: Ok, that is because of your regex. The answer was to address the rubocop error. To check the object is a Integer or not, you may try http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer

Comment: well, the other answer does both, is there a way to incorporate both? I would prefer to use regex in this case, it seems much easier

Comment: Why not try already attempted code ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061584/how-do-i-determine-if-a-string-is-numeric

Comment: the other one allows decimals... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661466/test-if-string-is-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @chrishough I use double `!!` a lot. I don't know why it is a bad idea though.

Comment: I ignored the cop after this chat, seems appropriate