# elegant way to check if a string inputed by user is an integer in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to validate that the input a user gives my program via `gets` is an integer. `is_a?(Integer)` does not work, as far as i can tell, because `gets` gets a string from the user, so it will always return false even if the user enters an valid integer (in string form). One would think I could simply use `to_i` on the input and be done with it, but that raises another issue - `"75akjfas".to_i` results in `75`. So if I relied on `to_i` to solve my problems, anything starting with numbers will work.

How do I cleanly validate that the value is an integer only, and not a combination of numbers and letters? Or do I need to resort to regex for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does ruby 1.9.2 have an is_a? function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282273/does-ruby-1-9-2-have-an-is-a-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `s.to_i.to_s == s`? I'd prefer regex however.

Comment: i have no reason to not use regexp. i'm just hoping there's a nice helper function somewhere that i'm missing :).

Answer (score 7):

```
print "Enter an integer (or try to sneak by something other): "
puts Integer(gets) rescue puts "Hey, that's not an integer!"
```

Comment: I'd just add a quote [from the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001434): "strings should be strictly conformed to numeric representation. This behavior is different from that of String#to_i"

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could do it like this:

```
class String
  def integer?
   !!(self =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Integer()` but you need to be careful with hex, binary, or octal input. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer

```
def valid_integer?(string)
  begin
    !!Integer(string)
  rescue ArgumentError
    false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code example for how to use the checked string input by the user
        puts "Enter a number: "
    user_input = gets.chomp
    check = (user_input.to_i.to_s == user_input)

```
while (!check ) do
 puts("Wrong Input, Pls, Enter a number: " )
 user_input = gets.chomp
  check = (user_input.to_i.to_s == user_input)
end

if user_input.to_i < 0
puts "Number is negative"
elsif user_input.to_i > 0
puts "Number is positve"
else
puts "Number is Zero"
end
```

Comment: The link you have provided yields an application error.  Maybe that is just a passing circumstance, but consider whether it is a lasting one you need to correct.  Also, the connection between the link you have provided and the sample code in your answer is not very clear.  Are they the same?  Edit your answer to make it clear.

Comment: thanks @J0e3gan i have removed the link and it does show the same thing just that you can be able to run it there... I noticed the link was private to me.

Answer (score -2):

Ruby can do it without esoteric solutions:

Integer is a integer

```
1970.is_a?Integer
true
```

String is not a integer

```
"1970".is_a?Integer
false
```

String to integer is a integer

```
"1970".to_i.is_a?Integer
true
```

Comment: This seems not to be totally correct. @LyleDickie wrote this as a suggested edit:
Unfortunately the "String to integer is a integer" section is incorrect. If you run it in IRB it does return true. However, if the user were to enter "197e" it would also evaluate to true.

```
 "197e".to_i.is_a?Integer
true
```

Comment: "a".to_i is 0. Which is still an integer.